# android style is not taken into account

Tags: android

I have a problem while creating styles in android:

When I use

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

in Button for instance, that's working fine, but if I create a styles.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="smalltext" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and replace in Button:

```
style="@style/smalltext"
```

nothing is taken into account.

Would you have any idea of what could be wrong ?

thanks a lot,
Luc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that styles will not be applied in the layout view in Eclipse.  You'll have to deploy the application to a device (or the emulator) to see the changes.

Comment: That was something I didn't know... :-( I'll check this tonight.
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the problem.
By the way, eclipse seems to complain with the following item in the styles.xml:
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>

where as android:textAppearance=?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall is the correct one for other widget for instance.

I cannot find the correct syntax in google.
Thanks a lot,
Luc